# We used to take our books out

Tags: word-choice

I don't know if you have similar desks, but I am talking about the desks in which you could put your books. Is the sentence clear for a native speaker?
"We used to take our books out of our desks for the next class.

Comment: 1) It's nice to ask one question at a time; if you'd like to ask about blackboards maybe that should be a separate question. 2) It's still not clear what we're evaluating. The tense of the verb "used to take"? The word "desks"? Please identify specific things you're concerned about.

Comment: Yes, "take our books out of out desks" is exactly the idiomatic way to say that.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite clear to me, but then I also used such a desk many years ago. Additional context might help to evaluate if it is likely to be clear to others. What makes you think that it is not clear?

Comment: It's written by me, a non-native speaker. I was afraid it wouldn't be clear :)

Comment: do native speakers use  "clean the board" or "clean the blackboard"? In a classroom.

Comment: @Antonia A they did, when  blackboards were common. They still do when writing of such times. However, note that "***clear** the board*" is a common expression with a quite different meaning: it means to deal with all outstanding issues. See the somewhat similar expression "[clear the decks](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/to-clear-the-decks)"

Comment: what do native speakers use nowadays?

Comment: @Antonia A Current schools (at least those I know about) mostly do not have blackboards, so there is no need to clean a blackboard. Some use whiteboards, which are cleaned in a similar way, and "clean" is a likely verb for the purpose, although "erase" is also common. Some use digital displays, which might be "cleared" but as this is a much quicker and simpler task, it is less likely to be mentioned at all. The phrase used depends on the acts to be described.

Comment: As "blackboard" and "boards" are still used here what would you suggest using?

Comment: @ David Siegel can't edit my comment.

Comment: @Antonia A  In discussing any school, current or past, where blackboards are used, it would be very natural to say "clean the blackboard" or "clean the board" if context made it clear what board is meant. The only reason for the expression being less used is that blackboards are less used. Comments can only be edited for 5 minutes once they are posted, after that a new comment must be posted instead.

Comment: @ David Siegel, thank you very much.